# Matplotlib cannot show figure warning when updating package in pip and sphinx

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip, python-sphinx

I updated my Python package in pip and sphinx. When I updated a figure (a scatterplot) in my documentation (via sphinx), I am getting this error message below when I generated one of the documentation webpages which contains this figure:

```
C:\Users\HP\Desktop\...(my own directory)...: UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
  plt.show()
```

The figure did not update to the new one. It is using an old figure that I previously had.

The code used to generate the figure is located here my documentation: https://helstrom-quantum-centroid-classifier.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/plot_hqc.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-plot-hqc-py

I have updated my Python package before in the past and never had this issue. Could potentially be a `pip` package management problem, where one of the `pip` packages got updated and wasn't updated in downstream `pip` packages.

I have tried uninstalling `matplotlib` and reinstalling `matplotlib`, it didn't work. My `matplotlib` version is now 3.3.0.

Would be great if the guys/gals at `pip` could have a look at this.

**Edit:** I am not sure what is happening, but the figure seems to display correctly (ie. displaying the updated one) on my "live" documentation webpage. In the `index.html` file in my computer, it's still showing the old figure and it has that error message I mentioned above. The `index.html` file should have updated itself when I executed the the command `make html`, but this time it didn't. Anyone has any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `plt.show()` the graph. Use `plt.savefig("nameofpic.png")` function to save the figure as png file and view it. Try it out.

Comment: Thanks @T.K.Gowtham, I guess I can do this manually like you suggested. Would prefer though if this gets fixed up for cases when I have future updates to my Python package. I updated my Python package in the past before, but this has never happened before.